# Не отображается сайт.

Tags: c#

Всем привет, я решил сделать небольшой редактор html, так вот, я хочу чтобы как только пользователь внёс какие-то изменения в код они сразу-же отобразились с браузере. Я сделал так:

```
 private void richCode_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richCode.SaveFile("index.html", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
            webSite.Navigate("index.html");
        }
```

Однако, браузер после недолгих раздумий пишет что не может отобразить страницу, а если я пишу такой путь:

```
D:\\index.html
```

То всё работает. Как исправить, чтобы файл index.html лежал в папке с .exe и мог отображаться браузером? Файл сохранятся, только браузер не отображает его.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1:** Хранить файл в папке с программой очень плохо (Если вы будете делать полноценное приложение, то вы не получите доступ на этот файл из программы без прав суперпользователя в win 7 | Vista.

**2:** Получить путь к исполняемому файлу можно через

```
var ExecutableDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

**3:** Зачем Вам вообще сохранять при каждом чихе на диск, почему не грузить из памяти?

```
 webSite.DocumentText = richCode.Text;
```

**4:** Файлы лучше хранить по этому пути:

```
var DataDir = Application.CommonAppDataPath;
```

Comment: Вот спасибо вам! Больше всего понравилось 3 пункт! Спасибо)