# Как узнать директорию exe-шника Windows-службы, написанной на C# ?

Tags: c#, windows-service

Есть простенькая, пока служба получающая получающая данные по сети и записывающая их в БД.
Служба должна при запуске читать настройки из xml-конфига, который лежит вместе с ней. При необходимости может его перечитывать в процессе работы (есть определенные условия для этого).

Проблема в том что путь **./** определяется не к exe-шнику службы, а системной папке **system32**. 
Как определить путь к каталогу в котором лежит exe-шник ?

PS Варианты типа, прописать полный путь или рассчитать его к папке в Program Files или ещё где - не подходит, так как *exe-шник* может *не лежать в системных папках*, и где бы то ни было *не хранится путь к нему* (например, в реестре).

Comment: Если это служба, то в реестре путь то должен быть к ней, иначе как винда поймёт что есть что?

Comment: Я надеюсь, что есть способ попроще...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрите [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/124818/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA-dll) ответ:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

Можно попробовать [ещё](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/123894/%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82) (Только не уверен что у службы это есть):

```
var ExecutableDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

И еще один вариант:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, А можно узнать зачем менять мой ответ?